# counter example for $\mathbb{E}[\log(x)] <\mathbb{E}[\log(y)]$ when $\mathbb{E}[x]< \mathbb{E}[y]$ and vice versa

Tags: statistics, inequality, expectation, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for an example that $\mathbb{E}[x]< \mathbb{E}[y]$ but not $\mathbb{E}[\log(x)] <\mathbb{E}[\log(y)]$ and an example that $\mathbb{E}[\log(x)] <\mathbb{E}[\log(y)]$ but not $\mathbb{E}[x]< \mathbb{E}[y]$.

Is there any such example? Or are they equivalent conditions?

Please note we can assume both $x,y\geq 0$.

Comment: What do you know about convexity?

Comment: @JohnHughes Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @julypraise $x\mapsto -\log x$ is convex. We also have that $x\mapsto \log x$ is monotone. What does Jensen's inequality tell you about the relationship between your two conditions?

Comment: @JalexStark $\mathbb{E} \log x < \log \mathbb{E} y$

Comment: @julypraise Do you mean to assume something about $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @JalexStark I intend not to except $x,y>0$. The problematic part for me is the relation between $\log \mathbb{E} y$ and $\mathbb{E} \log y$. I found in google something about reverse-Jensen's. But not sure if applicable for this type of problem.

Comment: @JalexStark And let me clarify that what I can prove is if $\mathbb{E} x < \mathbb{E} y$ then $\mathbb{E} \log x < \log \mathbb{E} y$.But as it is too trivial, I didn't include in my post.

Comment: @julypraise Ah. I was hinting towards the inequality in your last comment, not realizing that it doesn't resolve your question. mzp's answer does it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x=1$ with certainty and $y$ is equal to $0.4$ or $2$ with equal probability. Then
$$ \mathbb E[x] = 1 \lt 1.2 = \mathbb E[y],$$
and
$$ \mathbb E[\log(x)] = 0 \gt -0.11157 \approx \mathbb E[\log(y)].$$
Flip $x$ and $y$ and you get your other example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.